# How to introduce missing values in time series data

Tags: python, dataframe, time, time-series, nan

I'm new to python and also new to this site. My colleague and I are working on a time series dataset. we wish to introduce some missing values to the dataset and then use some techniques to fill in the missing values to see how well those techniques perform for the data imputation task. The challenge we have at the moment is how to introduce missing values to the dataset in a consecutive manner and not just randomly. For example, we want to replace data for a period of time with NaNs, eg, 3 consecutive days. I will really appreciate if anyone can point us in the right direction on how to get this done. we are working with python.

[Here is my sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEkBj.png)

Comment: To make my question more clear, here is a link to a sample of the data i'm currently working on. https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:ec15fbb4-6bed-412d-9713-a3616c8871a9 . I want to be able to replace values with NaNs on a consecutive basis, i.e values for 3 consecutive hours should be replaced with NANs

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for filling NaNs

```
dataframe['name_of_column'].fillna('value')
```

Comment: Thanks so much Alona for responding to my question. I appreciate this.I'm not trying to fill in missing values in this case rather, i am trying to introduce some missing values to my time series dataset. For example, my dataset contains data recorded every hour for 4 months, I wish to replace 3 consecutive days with NAN values. How can i achieve this

Comment: Dear  @lilfavour you have to edit your main post and add an example of you data. Then we will be able to give you suggestion. And also peace of code where you were trying to solve the problem. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok, I will do just that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See `set_missing_data` function below:

```py
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, linewidth=1000)

def set_missing_data(data, missing_locations, missing_length):
    for i in missing_locations:
        data[i:i+missing_length] = np.nan


np.random.seed(0)
n_data_points = np.random.randint(40, 50)
data = np.random.normal(size=[n_data_points])
n_missing = np.random.randint(3, 6)
missing_length = 3
missing_locations = np.random.choice(
    n_data_points - missing_length,
    size=n_missing,
    replace=False
)
print(data)
set_missing_data(data, missing_locations, missing_length)
print(data)
```

Console output:

```
[ 0.118  0.114  0.37   1.041 -1.517 -0.866 -0.055 -0.107  1.365 -0.098 -2.426 -0.453 -0.471  0.973 -1.278  1.437 -0.078  1.09   0.097  1.419  1.168  0.947  1.085  2.382 -0.406  0.266 -1.356 -0.114 -0.844  0.706 -0.399 -0.827 -0.416 -0.525  0.813 -0.229  2.162 -0.957  0.067  0.206 -0.457 -1.06   0.615  1.43  -0.212]
[ 0.118    nan    nan    nan -1.517 -0.866 -0.055 -0.107    nan    nan    nan -0.453 -0.471  0.973 -1.278  1.437 -0.078  1.09   0.097    nan    nan    nan  1.085  2.382 -0.406  0.266 -1.356 -0.114 -0.844  0.706 -0.399 -0.827 -0.416 -0.525  0.813 -0.229  2.162 -0.957  0.067  0.206 -0.457 -1.06   0.615  1.43  -0.212]
```

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks so much for your kind help. I'm trying to include my sample dataset, to help you understand exacly what i mean.

Comment: Hi Jake, a sample of my data could be found here: https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:ec15fbb4-6bed-412d-9713-a3616c8871a9

Comment: What is the format of your data within your Python program? A numpy array? A CSV file? A plain text file? Or do you only have PDFs of your data?

Comment: The data is on a csv file